# Auto suggest TextBox in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I am looking for a auto suggest TextBox in flex.

When i type a character,  a drop list within the textBox should display with matching words with the character that i have typed. please provide if have any example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following links might help you:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1047291

http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/

http://flashcommander.org/blog/flex-4-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Shameless ad plug for my InputAssist component

http://www.jabbypanda.com/blog/category/inputassist/